# Will getObjectSummaries get the count of objects stored in a S3 Bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to know the number of files that are stored under `S3` bucket. Currently, `ObjectListing` doesn't has a method such as `count` or `numberOfObject`.

However, it has a method that will return a List of `S3ObjectSummary`.

```
public java.util.List<S3ObjectSummary> getObjectSummaries()
```

Since it is a `List`, I can call `size()` method but is it accurate and right thing to assume that the size of `getObjectSummaries()` List is the same number of objects that are stored under a bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- it is more accurate to say that the size of `getObjectSummaries()` is the number of objects in the page of results from `listObjects()` that you received. Otherwise, yes -- it is correct that each object summary in the list should correspond to an S3 object.

AWS pages the results of large result sets to 1,000 results per page.  In a general case, you will need to expect to make this call more than once:

- If [isTruncated()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#isTruncated()) is true, call [getNextMarker()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getNextMarker()) to get the next marker to use in your next ListObjectsRequest to [listObjects()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest)).
- If false, this last response you got will be the last one you need to handle. You can finish counting your objects at this point.

With that in mind, this isn't a great solution for very large buckets since you have to enumerate the whole bucket.  Here's [an alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026892/775544) using [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) that you may be able to call from Java.