# How to count the total number of objects in an S3 bucket using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, s3-bucket

I am trying to find a faster way to count all of the objects within an s3 bucket using Amazon's AWS SDK.

```
private static int getBucketFileCount(AmazonS3 s3, ListObjectsV2Request req) {
   ListObjectsV2Result result;
   int fileCount = 0;
   log.info("Counting s3 files");

   do {
      result = s3.listObjectsV2(req);
      for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
         fileCount++;
      }
      req.setContinuationToken(result.getNextContinuationToken());

   } while (result.isTruncated() == true);
       return fileCount;
}
```

However, this method is very slow and I have not been able to figure out a way to do it properly. I have found another answer that sort of helps, but cannot figure out the implementation exactly.
[Will getObjectSummaries get the count of objects stored in a S3 Bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118398)

How do I use the [getNextMarker()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getNextMarker()) function with my current implementation? What do I need to change?

Comment: I noticed you have `fileCount += result.getKeyCount()` as well as `fileCount++` inside a for loop. Are you double counting?

Comment: Ah my bad, that was something I forgot to remove

Comment: If you don't require an up-to-date count value, [Amazon S3 Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) is a scheduled alternative to the Amazon S3 synchronous List API operation. It provides a comma-separated values (.csv) flat-file output of your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113605/will-getobjectsummaries-get-the-count-of-objects-stored-in-a-s3-bucket for answer.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal I already linked to that post. I still do not understand how exactly to use those functions since I am not well versed in aws sdk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will getObjectSummaries get the count of objects stored in a S3 Bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113605/will-getobjectsummaries-get-the-count-of-objects-stored-in-a-s3-bucket)